# Merge multiple images matplotlib

Tags: python

My for loop creates 99 images. I want to display all these images into one image, not 99 separate files. 
Currently, it will only show the last image created. However, I want one image all merged together)

```
For track in c:
    plt.imshow(k.getCookie(track,50))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

If you for example want a grid of 11x9 elements

```
for i,track in enumerate(c):
    plt.subplot(11,9,i+1)
    plt.imshow(k.getCookie(track,50))
```